# How to check the api response body using Mockito on android?

Tags: android, mockito

I am new to unit testing. My requirement is to check the response is in correct format or not. I am posting the code that I have done. Is this correct way to implement the Mockito. While compiling the code it throws me the error, saying Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock. Can you give some idea how to mock test for response format?

```
public class SignUpTest {
    MockWebServer mockWebServer;

    @Mock
    ApiInterface apiInterface;

    @Mock
    Call<ResponseBody> responseBodyCall;


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    }

    @Test
    public void testWithCorrect() throws Exception {
        String format = "{" +
                "\"Status\":null," +
                "\"Message\":null," +
                "\"IssueId\":null," +
                "\"TransId\":null," +
                "\"ResponseCode\":101," +
                "\"ResponseDescription\":\"APP requires your phone id while registering app." +
                " Please provide necessary permission to the app before proceeding.\"" +
                "}";
        JsonObject jsonParam = new JsonObject();
        jsonParam.addProperty("msisdn", "9812345678");
        when(apiInterface.appLogin(jsonParam)).thenReturn(responseBodyCall);
        verify(responseBodyCall).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResponseBody> call, @NonNull Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                assert response.body() != null;
                assertEquals(format, response.body().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ResponseBody> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: You are not actually running the code anywhere. Something like loginClass.doLogin()

Comment: @Smashing I want to check the response that come from the server and the string that I have provided must be equal. How to do that??

Comment: Shouldn't the server handle tests with regards to the responses? What I am trying to say is shouldn't your network layer be separately tested from your business logic? So the ApiInterface returns a string result or object rather than a retrofit call. Returning a retrofit call will create a hard dependency on retrofit.